# Android MenuItem Toggle Button

Tags: android, button, toggle, menuitem, togglebutton

In my Android application, I want a setting to be toggleable in it's menu like the Dialer app does for speaker and mute. You can see a picture below:

http://www.isaacwaller.com/images/acall.png

You see how the Speaker, Mute and Hold options are toggle buttons - you can tap them again and they will toggle the green color. They may do this in a custom way, but I suspect it is a option (I tried setting the Checkable attribute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's looks like this menu item is implemented as a custom view.

In the android source code you can take a look at [com.android.phone.InCallMenuView.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/phone/InCallMenuView.java) to see how this is implemented.

It doesn't look like it is part of the public API, but it looks pretty self-contained.  If your project has a compatible license, you may be able to copy it into your project and use and modify it as you see fit.

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like the snippet below as well, originally sourced from [anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/)

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {       
      if(super.mMapView.isTraffic()) 
           menu.findItem(MENU_TRAFFIC_ID).setIcon(R.drawable.traffic_off_48); 
      else 
           menu.findItem(MENU_TRAFFIC_ID).setIcon(R.drawable.traffic_on_48); 

      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
 }
```