# Change background color of android menu

Tags: android, menu, background, layout-inflater

I'm trying to change the standard light grey to a light green. Seems that there is not a simple way to do this (through Android Themes, for example) but I have found a workaround as explained at this page: http://tinyurl.com/342dgn3.

The author seems disappeared, can someone help me integrating this code?  I don't understand where I need to implement the `LayoutInflater` factory class.

Comment: If someone is interested i've solved. http://pastebin.com/1QHGTMUW
just call the setMenuBackground in the onCreate

Comment: Here's how I got custom Action Bar menu background colour working on Android 4.0+: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077381/56285

Comment: i try you code, but it first tell me to remove @Override and then nothings hapens. I tried to change the menue back ground color.

Comment: it's wont work on 4.3 api why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When ur are inflating the menu call this setMenuBackground()  method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    setMenuBackground(); 
    return true;    
}
```

and write this in the setMenuBackground()  method

```
    protected void setMenuBackground(){                     
        // Log.d(TAG, "Enterting setMenuBackGround");  
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory( new Factory() {  
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" ) ) {
                    try { // Ask our inflater to create the view  
                        LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();  
                        final View view = f.createView( name, null, attrs );  
                        /* The background gets refreshed each time a new item is added the options menu.  
                        * So each time Android applies the default background we need to set our own  
                        * background. This is done using a thread giving the background change as runnable 
                        * object */
                        new Handler().post( new Runnable() {  
                            public void run () {  
                                // sets the background color   
                                view.setBackgroundResource( R.color.androidcolor);
                                // sets the text color              
                                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                // sets the text size              
                                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(18);
                }
                        } );  
                    return view;
                }
            catch ( InflateException e ) {}
            catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {}  
        } 
        return null;
    }}); 
}
```

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work? Seems to have no effect (Gingerbread)

Comment: It works with android 2.2 haven't checked with 2.3

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me (on Android 4.0+). `com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView`does not match anything, and when I changed that to `com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView`, my app just crashes when opening the menu. With `TextView` I got it to change *a part* of menu items' background color, but not everything. In every case, this seems hacky and prone to breaking with future Android versions.

Comment: the only thing I get is  "java.lang.illegalstateexception: a factory has already been set on this layoutinflater" for android 2.3+ and 4.0+ devices.

Comment: It's wont work for me too .@Jonik  did you solve your problem? so let me know

Comment: @AbhayKumar can you please describe  about 'imports'. I am getting `java.lang.illegalstateexception: a factory has already been set on this layoutinflater` error. please help me.

Comment: Same error has shown to me please recommend something to solve this one :)

Comment: any update for androidx and kotlin ?

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly a problem that a lot of programmers have and to which Google has yet to provide a satisfactory, supported solution.

The setMenuBackground() hack which Abhay Kumar and Nik Reiman posted is a good start but it either crashes or does not work on Android 2.3.

Please see my answer (Louis Semprini) in this stackoverflow question for a better commented and more refined hack that works on 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3 (and that should do no harm on 3.X, though we can never guarantee this):

[How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu/8475357#8475357)

Also, here are many other resources you may find helpful for this question:

[Change background color of android menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu)

[Android: customize application's menu (e.g background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color)

http://www.macadamian.com/blog/post/android_-_theming_the_unthemable/

[Android MenuItem Toggle Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568533/android-menuitem-toggle-button)

[Is it possible to make the Android options menu background non-translucent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217886/is-is-possible-to-make-the-android-options-menu-background-non-translucent)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx

[Setting the menu background to be opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621609/setting-the-menu-background-to-be-opaque)

Answer (score 0):

Use the setMenuBackground in onCreate.

Comment: oops i see that you already answered your own question. nice job.

Comment: where??  which OnCreate