# How do I color the text of the options menu in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have a popup theme that is properly setting the background color, but doesn't change the text color. How do I do that?

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/green</item>

    <!-- These are not being applied -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a problem that a lot of programmers have and to which Google has yet to provide a satisfactory, supported solution.

There are a lot of crossed intentions and misunderstandings floating around posts on this topic, so please read this whole answer before responding.

Below I include a more "refined" and well-commented version of the hack from other answers on this page, also incorporating ideas from these very closely related questions:

[Change background color of android menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu)

[How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu)

[Android: customize application's menu (e.g background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color)

http://www.macadamian.com/blog/post/android_-_theming_the_unthemable/

[Android MenuItem Toggle Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568533/android-menuitem-toggle-button)

[Is it possible to make the Android options menu background non-translucent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217886/is-is-possible-to-make-the-android-options-menu-background-non-translucent)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx

[Setting the menu background to be opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621609/setting-the-menu-background-to-be-opaque)

I tested this hack on 2.1 (simulator), 2.2 (2 real devices), and 2.3 (2 real devices).  I don't have any 3.X tablets to test on yet but will post any needed changes here when/if I do.  Given that 3.X tablets use Action Bars instead of Options Menus, as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

this hack will almost certainly do nothing (no harm and no good) on 3.X tablets.

STATEMENT OF THE PROBLEM (read this before trigger-replying with a negative comment):

The Options menu has vastly different styles on different devices.  Pure black with white text on some, pure white with black text on some.  I and many other developers wish to control the background color of the Options menu cells **as well as the color of the Options menu text**.

Certain app developers only need to set the cell background color (not the text color), and they can do this in a cleaner manner using the android:panelFullBackground style described in another answer.  However, there is currently no way to control the Options menu text color with styles, and so one can only use this method to change the background to another color that won't make the text "disappear."

We would love to do this with a documented, future-proof solution, but one is simply not available as of Android <= 2.3.  So we have to use a solution that works in current versions and is designed to minimize the chances of crashing/breaking in future versions.  We want a solution that fails gracefully back to the default behavior if it has to fail.

There are many legitimate reasons why one may need to control the look of Options menus (typically to match a visual style for the rest of the app) so I won't dwell on that.

There is a Google Android bug posted about this: please add your support by starring this bug (note Google discourages "me too" comments: just a star is enough):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4441

SUMMARY OF SOLUTIONS SO FAR:

Several posters have suggested a hack involving LayoutInflater.Factory.  The suggested hack worked for Android <= 2.2 and failed for Android 2.3 because the hack made an undocumented assumption: that one could call LayoutInflater.getView() directly without currently being inside a call to LayoutInflater.inflate() on the same LayoutInflater instance.  New code in Android 2.3 broke this assumption and led to a NullPointerException.

My slightly refined hack below does not rely on this assumption.

Furthermore, the hacks also rely on using an internal, undocumented class name "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" as a string (not as a Java type).  I do not see any way to avoid this and still accomplish the stated goal.  However, it is possible to do the hack in a careful way that will fall back if "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" does not appear on the current system.

Again, understand that this is a hack and by no means am I claiming this will work on all platforms.  But we developers are not living in a fantasy academic world where everything has to be by the book: we have a problem to solve and we have to solve it as best we can.  For example, it seems unlikely that "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" will exist on 3.X tablets since they use Action Bars instead of Options Menus.

Finally, some developers have solved this problem by totally suppressing the Android Options Menu and writing their own menu class (see some of the links above).  I haven't tried this, but if you have time to write your own View and figure out how to replace Android's view (I'm sure the devil's in the details here) then it might be a nice solution that doesn't require any undocumented hacks.

HACK:

Here is the code.

To use this code, call addOptionsMenuHackerInflaterFactory() ONCE from your activity onCreate() or your activity onCreateOptionsMenu().  It sets a default factory that will affect subsequent creation of any Options Menu.  It does not affect Options Menus that have already been created (the previous hacks used a function name of setMenuBackground(), which is very misleading since the function doesn't set any menu properties before it returns).

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
static Class       IconMenuItemView_class = null;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
static Constructor IconMenuItemView_constructor = null;

// standard signature of constructor expected by inflater of all View classes
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static final Class[] standard_inflater_constructor_signature = 
new Class[] { Context.class, AttributeSet.class };

protected void addOptionsMenuHackerInflaterFactory()
{
    final LayoutInflater infl = getLayoutInflater();

    infl.setFactory(new Factory()
    {
        public View onCreateView(final String name, 
                                 final Context context,
                                 final AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView"))
                return null; // use normal inflater

            View view = null;

            // "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" 
            // - is the name of an internal Java class 
            //   - that exists in Android <= 3.2 and possibly beyond
            //   - that may or may not exist in other Android revs
            // - is the class whose instance we want to modify to set background etc.
            // - is the class we want to instantiate with the standard constructor:
            //     IconMenuItemView(context, attrs)
            // - this is what the LayoutInflater does if we return null
            // - unfortunately we cannot just call:
            //     infl.createView(name, null, attrs);
            //   here because on Android 3.2 (and possibly later):
            //   1. createView() can only be called inside inflate(),
            //      because inflate() sets the context parameter ultimately
            //      passed to the IconMenuItemView constructor's first arg,
            //      storing it in a LayoutInflater instance variable.
            //   2. we are inside inflate(),
            //   3. BUT from a different instance of LayoutInflater (not infl)
            //   4. there is no way to get access to the actual instance being used
            // - so we must do what createView() would have done for us
            //
            if (IconMenuItemView_class == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    IconMenuItemView_class = getClassLoader().loadClass(name);
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    // this OS does not have IconMenuItemView - fail gracefully
                    return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
                }
            }
            if (IconMenuItemView_class == null)
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater

            if (IconMenuItemView_constructor == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    IconMenuItemView_constructor = 
                    IconMenuItemView_class.getConstructor(standard_inflater_constructor_signature);
                }
                catch (SecurityException e)
                {
                    return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
                }
                catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
                {
                    return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
                }
            }
            if (IconMenuItemView_constructor == null)
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater

            try
            {
                Object[] args = new Object[] { context, attrs };
                view = (View)(IconMenuItemView_constructor.newInstance(args));
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
            }
            catch (InstantiationException e)
            {
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater
            }
            if (null == view) // in theory handled above, but be safe... 
                return null; // hack failed: use normal inflater


            // apply our own View settings after we get back to runloop
            // - android will overwrite almost any setting we make now
            final View v = view;
            new Handler().post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                    try
                    {
                        // in Android <= 3.2, IconMenuItemView implemented with TextView
                        // guard against possible future change in implementation
                        TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    catch (ClassCastException e)
                    {
                        // hack failed: do not set TextView attributes
                    }
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for reading and enjoy!

Comment: I've read that post as you keep posting it everywhere and it does not hold the answer. I found the answer (but it makes no sense). If I set `<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupTheme</item>` in my app's theme and then set the `textColor` inside that theme, it works.