# changing the background color of menu

Tags: android

Hello i have the following xml for menu i want to set the background color black like over [here](http://android.ankara-gtug.org/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) . The other thing i want to set if the buttons are increased they should remain in one row instead of moving to next row . Thanks

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


         <item android:id="@+id/Quit"
        android:title="Quit"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />

        <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />


        <item android:id="@+id/services"
        android:title="Services"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />

        <item android:id="@+id/web"
        android:title="web"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />




</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the background color, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu) and it's comments.

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this by creating custom menus.

checkout this [url](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx) for help.