# How to tell what the Android menu color is

Tags: android, android-menu

I have seen questions that ask about changing the Android menu background color.  I do not want to do this, I just want to determine if the menu is dark or light and show a different icon accordingly.

How can you tell if the Android menu background is dark or light?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been described before. And here are some answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color) (by wiseman)

## Edit:

Didn't try by myself but you may do something with following code:

```
getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(android.R.attr.windowBackground);
```

It returns `TypedArray` from which you can obtain the value of attribute somehow.

Comment: those questions describe how to set the background color, but all I am trying to do is determine if the background color is light or dark.  Is there a way to do this?