# Change the color of a checked menu item in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I am using the new Android Design Support library to implement a navigation drawer in my application.

**I can't figure out how to change the color of a selected item!**

Here is the xml of the menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_1"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_2"/>
</group>
```

And here is the navigationview xml which is placed inside a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Thank you for your help !

[EDIT]
I have already looked at solutions such as this one : [Change background color of android menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu).

It seems to be quite a hack and I thought that with the new Design Support Library, something cleaner would have been introduced?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Well you can achieve this using [Color State Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). If you notice inside your `NavigationView` you're using

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
```

Here instead of using `@color/black` or `@color/primary_test`, use a `Color State List Resource`. For that, first create a new `xml` (e.g drawer_item.xml) inside `color` directory (which should be inside `res` directory.) If you don't have a directory named `color` already, create one.

Now inside `drawer_item.xml` do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="checked state color" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="your default color" />
</selector>
```

Final step would be to change your `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"  // notice here
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item" // and here
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"// and here for setting the background color to tranparent
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

Like this you can use separate Color State List Resources for `IconTint`, `ItemTextColor`, `ItemBackground`.

Now when you set an item as checked (either in `xml` or programmatically), the particular item will have different color than the unchecked ones.

Comment: Remember that for pressed to work you need to change it from  android:state_checked to android:state_pressed.

Comment: for ItemBackground you need to use a drawable instead of color because you cannot define a background using a color resource.

Comment: @sash if we want to do change icon image on select navigation item then how we will do this ?

Comment: @sirFunkenstine If you are using color selector then you can put it in color   folder  in your res folder.

Comment: @KishanVaghela doing what you suggests produces this error:         Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: @aqm, you will need to update itemBackground to be `app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"`. If it still does not work for you. Please provide the error you are seeing.

Comment: It is working for me, but I had to explicitly set setNavigationItemSelectedListener and set the checked property of the menu item to true. like this: menuItem.setChecked(true).

Comment: **DON'T FORGET TO APPLY "CHECKABLE=TRUE" IN YOUR MENU XML FOR THE BACKGROUND TO WORK PROPERLY**

Answer (score 83):

I believe `app:itemBackground` expects a drawable. So follow the steps below :

Make a drawable file `highlight_color.xml` with following contents :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="YOUR HIGHLIGHT COLOR"/>
</shape>
```

Make another drawable file `nav_item_drawable.xml` with following contents:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_color" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Finally add `app:itemBackground` tag in the NavView :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_drawable"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

here the highlight_color.xml file defines a solid color drawable for the background. Later this color drawable is assigned to nav_item_drawable.xml selector.

This worked for me. Hopefully this will help.

**********************************************  **UPDATED**  **********************************************

Though the above mentioned answer gives you fine control over some properties, but the way I am about to describe feels more **SOLID** and is a bit **COOLER**.

So what you can do is, you can define a **ThemeOverlay** in the `styles.xml` for the NavigationView like this :

```
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme">

        <!-- Color of text and icon when SELECTED -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_of_your_choice</item> 

        <!-- Background color when SELECTED -->
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_of_your_choice</item> 

    </style>
```

now apply this ThemeOverlay to `app:theme` attribute of NavigationView, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Also, this method can be used as `android:background="@drawable/nav_item_drawable"` for other widgets like RadioButton, Checkbox, Button etc. Reduces bloatware programming for handling `setOnCheckedChangeListener` just for color highlighting.

Comment: @Ankush 
this works but text and icon disappears, i have set the item tint color too but its not working. can you please suggest me how it can be done

Comment: @User I don't know what went wrong with your code, but I have added onto the answer. An entirely different way to achieve the same thing with less effort. You can check that out.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer! Thank you very much, very helpful!!!

Comment: **DON'T FORGET TO APPLY "CHECKABLE=TRUE" IN YOUR MENU XML FOR THE BACKGROUND TO WORK PROPERLY**

Comment: if i want diferent color wnite<-> yelow on first item and white<-> red on second item?

Answer (score 6):

One need to set `NavigateItem` checked true whenever item in `NavigateView` is clicked

```
//listen for navigation events
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
// select the correct nav menu item
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(mNavItemId).setChecked(true);
```

Add `NavigationItemSelectedListener` on `NavigationView`

```
  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
    // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    mNavItemId = menuItem.getItemId();

    // allow some time after closing the drawer before performing real navigation
    // so the user can see what is happening
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        navigate(menuItem.getItemId());
      }
    }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Vikalp, but I am already doing that (`setChecked(true)`).
I can see the color of the checked item changing but I can't modify it myself, the color is always a lighter version of the navigatioview background.

Comment: @Greg By default `setChecked(true)` on `View` changes background color upto theme that device you uses. If you to change background of item to some other color then you need to inflate your layout  in `DrawerLayout` or `NavigationView` and handle on your own.

Comment: thanks again, I have tried to do what you told me but without success, would you have a link explaining how please ?

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:**  Build a checked/unchecked selector:

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/yellow" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

**Step 2:**  use the `XML` attribute `app:itemTextColor` within `NavigationView` widget for selecting the text color.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

**Step 3 & 4:**

**Step 3:** To make menu icons check-able: wrap all items in a `<group>` and set`android:checkableBehavior="single"`

**Step 4:** To change icon color: set the selector to all the items with `app:iconTint`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_account"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:title="My Account"
            app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="Settings"
            app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout"
            android:title="Log Out"
            app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

**Step 5:**: make sure that `onNavigationItemSelected()` callback returns true to consume selection event

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Result:

[image]

**Side Note:**

If setting `android:checkableBehavior="single"` not working, then you handle this programmatically by manually making the selected item checked and clear the previously selected item:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    
    // remove all colors of the items to the `unchecked` state of the selector
    removeColor(mNavigationView);
    
    // check the selected item to change its color set by the `checked` state of the selector
    item.setChecked(true);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.dashboard:
          ...
    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void removeColor(NavigationView view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < view.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = view.getMenu().getItem(i);
        item.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i can diferent color wnite<-> yelow on first item and white<-> red on second item?

Comment: @Fortran If I understand you well, I think you need different colors for different Nav Drawer items; then you can create multiple selector drawable, each with different color; and use `app:iconTint="@drawable/selector" ` with the particular selector you want

Answer (score 3):

Here is the another way to achive this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            item.setEnabled(true);
            item.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff3824'>Settings</font>"));
            return false;
            }
        });


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: My dobut was regarding what if I want to change color of selected item of popup menu, but thanks to you that i got one great idea from your this solution to change color of selected menu item... so giving you vote !!! 
And the work around is like ::

item.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff3824'>Settings</font>"));

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it in your Activity's onCreate method:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(
    new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked}  // checked
    },
    new int[] {
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.RED
    }
);
navigationView.setItemTextColor(csl);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(csl);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the fillet of selected item in material 3, use app:itemShapeFillColor="@color/main_navigation_view" instead of app:itemBackground="@color/main_navigation_view"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).