# How to style the Design Support library's NavigationView?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

So I'm using the NavigationView provided by [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

[image]

I can't seem to find examples on how to style it.

So far I have:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"/>
```

Styling the header is easy as its under its own xml layout but the body is a menu resource file and not a layout.

- `app:itemTextColor` changes the text color
- `app:itemIconTint` changes the icon color
- `app:itemBackground` changes the item background color

So how to set

- selected item background
- selected item text color
- selected item icon tint

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have answered to a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31074133/23195420).

Basically what you need do is , use a `Color State List Resource`. For that , first create a new `xml` (e.g drawer_item.xml) inside `color` directory (which should be inside `res` directory.) If you don't have a directory named color already , create one.

Now inside `drawer_item.xml` do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="checked state color" android:state_checked= "true" />
    <item android:color="your default color" />
</selector>
```

For `itemBackground`, a separate drawable needs to be placed inside drawable folder too. The name is same `drawer_item`. `android:drawable` property needs to be set instead of `android:color` for `itemBackground`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/shape_rectangle_checked"

        android:state_checked= "true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_rectangle" />

</selector>
```

File `shape_rectangle`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" /> <!--white color -->
</shape>
```

File `shape_rectangle_checked`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#25aaf1" /> <!--blue color -->
</shape>
```

and then set in your navigationview like this

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item" //notice here
app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item" //and here
app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"//and here for changing the background color of the item which is checked
```

Comment: I put the xml under res/color but it says `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/drawer_menu_item.xml from drawable resource`

Comment: Please check my edit and lemme know if it worked for you.

Comment: Adding drawables inside strings.xml .. Probably the best way to get yourself lost in your files :)

Comment: @geecko : Agree. However in this case the original solution which works usually didn't work for OP. So i suggested another way or even another way (in the link given).

Comment: @Sash_KP I can't use drawable in `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_menu_item"` because it requires requires a 'android:color' attribute.

Comment: @Sash_KP okay I dont know what I did wrong earlier but your first solution worked now.

Comment: Will this affect the ripple effect color too?

Comment: Setting the background color has no effect for me.

Comment: @ArjunU. how did you solved your error ? I am getting the same error but only when setting itemBackground

Comment: ah `app:itemBackground` should be a drawable

Comment: @Sash_KP Any idea on changing the list item height

Comment: I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633165/550471 worked very well

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Sash_KP's answer, for the `xml` in the `drawable` folder, you dont need the `@drawable/shape_rectangle` and `@drawable/shape_rectangle_check`. You can just use `@color/your_color`.

Also for `API >= 21`, I've noticed that the navigation menu items by default have a preset selector. You'll notice if you touch and hold down the menu item a ripple will appear. Using a custom `itemBackground` will not override the default ripple. Therefore if you use a `ripple drawable` it will create two ripples! Also menu items with `ripple drawables` do not allow you to have a pressed state for some reason (the default ripple will only appear if you HOLD down).

So for `API >= 21` I would not recommend using a `ripple drawable`. Just use a regular `selector drawable` with no custom ripples.