# NavigationView(Change Color of Selected Item)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigationview

Is there any way to change the Item color programmatically of the selected item
in the navigation drawer?
I'am able to use the app:itemTextColor,  but the problem is if i used this,
the checked in the menu item will not highlight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
            android:title="Search Location" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fav"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
            android:title="Favorites" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_route"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_place"
            android:title="Route" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_recent"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_route"
            android:title="Recent Location" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Others">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:checked="true"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="About" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Why you dont use linear layout with textviews or list view inside of navigation drawer it would be simpler for u to do whatever u want

Comment: Well. that doesn't answer my question. Sorry but I want to stick with the NavigationView

Comment: maybe this answer is helpfull for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 40, accepted):

create a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/primary" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and set

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_view_item_background"
```

then the selected item will be highlighted.

if you want to change the text color then set

```
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_view_item_textcolor"
```

and create a selector for it like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
     <item android:color="@color/primary" />
</selector>
```

Comment: This also worked for me, it's worth noting that the `app:itemTextColor` should be applied to the `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`.

Comment: If `state_checked` is not working try to use `state_pressed` instead

Comment: it is a better idea to use both of them state_pressed and state_checked. You must have the feedback as soon as you start pressing the button.

Answer (score 4):

**Note :** Yasoda's answer not worked for me, which is true in most of the cases.

Though I set the `state_checked` is **true** and give it a drawable color, it seems the item is never checked.

For more search, I found the issue was happened with menu item. I hadn't given checked item to true in menu item in menu file.

Then I have to add a tag `android:checkable=true` to it.

and it works like charm.

Comment: No it doesn't, after you clicked on the item it NEVER changed back to original color.

Comment: I was having the same issue, checkable attribute solved it. Thank you!