# Change the color of a checked menu item in a navigation drawer in different menus

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

This is my `activity_main_drawer.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_hasiera"
            android:title="@string/nav_hasiera" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_oharrak"
            android:title="@string/nav_oharrak" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_instalazioak"

            android:title="@string/nav_instalazioak" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gustokoak"
            android:title="@string/nav_gustokoak" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/filtrar_por">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_lokalizazioa"
                android:title="@string/nav_lokalizazio" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ekintzak"
                android:title="@string/nav_ekintzak" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ordutegia"
                android:title="@string/nav_ordutegia" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/opciones">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hizkuntza"

                android:title="@string/nav_hizkuntza" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

When I select `items` of `group` tag, the background color of the item changes. It is ok.

But when I select `items` of  `Filtrar por...` or `opciones`, the background color does not change.

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956978/navigationviewchange-color-of-selected-item) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer) but not fix my problem

**Edit:**
This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/donostiakirola_fondo_pantalla"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please show the code for changing the color also?

Comment: Now i don't write  code to change the color. Now it is default state and when I select some item, it's background color change to gray. I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `android:checkable` = "true" to the items of `Filtrar por...` and `opciones`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_hasiera"
            android:title="@string/nav_hasiera" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_oharrak"
            android:title="@string/nav_oharrak" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_instalazioak"

            android:title="@string/nav_instalazioak" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gustokoak"
            android:title="@string/nav_gustokoak" />   
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/filtrar_por">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_lokalizazioa"
                android:title="@string/nav_lokalizazio"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ekintzak"
                android:title="@string/nav_ekintzak"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ordutegia"
                android:title="@string/nav_ordutegia"
                android:checkable="true"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/opciones">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hizkuntza"
                android:title="@string/nav_hizkuntza"
                android:checkable="true"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ***res/color*** folder, add a ***navigation_bg_color.xml*** file.

And add the following code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/defaultBgColor"/> <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/selectedBackgroundColor" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/selectedBackgroundColor" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

And use the following code for activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/donostiakirola_fondo_pantalla"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemBackground="@color/navigation_bg_color"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And don't forget to declare color values in the *colors.xml* file: **defaultBgColor, selectedBackgroundColor**