# How to set the Color of the item title in navigationDrawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am stuck in my own code. I can't find where to set the color of the "Title" text, in the navigationDrawer, to the defualt gray.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemTextColor="your color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

**app:itemTextColor="your color"** only changes each item, like Import, Gallery etc. But how to change the **Communicate** textColor with the line above?

Picture 2 (dark blue) is what it looks like in my project. I managed to "somewhere" set the color to white in my project.

[image]

[image]

Can you find my problem? Currently my "Title" text is white..

**nav_header_main.xml**

> ```
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
>         android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
>         />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
>         android:textColor="@color/whiteGray"
>         android:text="@string/app_name"
>          />
>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**activity_main.xml**

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
>         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>         android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>         tools:openDrawer="start"
>         >
>
>         <include
>             layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>         <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>             android:id="@+id/nav_view"
>             android:background="@color/nav_drawer_background"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_gravity="start"
>             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>             app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
>             app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
>             app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_drawer_text" />
>
>         <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>             android:id="@+id/nav_right_view"
>             android:background="@color/nav_drawer_background"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_gravity="end"
>             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>             app:menu="@menu/activity_main_right_drawer"
>             app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_drawer_text" />
>
>
>     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
> ```

**app_bar_main.xml**

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
>     />
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
>
> <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
>     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
>      />
> ```

**values/style.xml**

> ```
>     <style name="WelcomeDialogTitle">
>         <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>         <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkblue</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkblue</item>
>         <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkblue</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
>         <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkblue</item>
>         <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
>         <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/transparent</item>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/transparent</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>     <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
>     <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
>         <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/CustomListView</item>
>         <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/CustomTextView</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="CustomListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
>         <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
>         <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="CustomTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
>         <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
>         <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
>         <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="TitleTextStyleLarge">
>         <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
>         <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/white</item>
>         <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
>         <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
>         <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="TitleTextStyle">
>         <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
>         <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
>         <!-- <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/white</item> -->
>         <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="BarTitleStyle">
>         <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_list_topbar</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_height">33dp</item>
>         <!-- <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/white</item> -->
>         <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="BarTitleProgressStyle">
>         <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_list_topbar</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_height">27dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_width">27dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">1dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
>         <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
>     </style>
>
> </resources>
> ```

**My activity theme**

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >
            <meta-data
```

**drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:title="@string/LabelSearchTabTitle" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_wiki"
            android:title="@string/LabelTitleWikiBook" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_forum"
            android:title="@string/LabelTitleForum"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_history"
            android:title="@string/LabelHistory"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_favs"
            android:title="@string/LabelFavourites"
            />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/LabelTitleSupportPages">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_options"
                android:title="@string/LabelTitleSettings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_qa"
                android:title="@string/LabelTitleAbout" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_facebook"
                android:title="@string/LabelTitleFB" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: past menu xml here

Comment: Not using any menu.xml as far as I know.

Comment: i guess this will help you:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer)

Comment: sorry i meant drawer.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try :**

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#eeeeee</item>
```

**Edit :**

**Replace :**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkblue</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**With This :**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkblue</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#eeeeee</item>
    </style>
```

**Edit 2 :**

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkblue</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

             // change header color       
           <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#eeeeee</item>
            // change separator color
            <item name="android:listDivider">#ff000000</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: Where shall I put this you mean?

Comment: put it inside the parent theme of your Class . For e.g
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 
    
   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#eeeeee</item>

</style> `

Comment: Or else post your activity theme .

Comment: can you pls post the crash log?

Comment: Well it solved the problem with the textColor. Thanks! The only problem now is that the line is still white...

Comment: @user1293618 you mean the divider?

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I found out that the real problem was:  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"> instead of  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">. I just removed the "parent" attribute...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom layout for your Drawer items and include the custom layout in NavigationView.. Like this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <include
            layout="@layout/sidedrawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

sidedrawer is your custom layout and you can provide it any style or color you want.. hope it will help you