# How to apply selector for selected item in navigation drawer Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, selector

I am using navigation activity in Android studio. I have tried code below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_bg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"

        app:itemIconTint="@color/color_white_transperntdark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_white_transperntdark"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

But below I need a kind of selector having some color and white vertical line. So give me a hint:

[image]

Comment: i got answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31074133/3506117