# Android: how to change selected item color in Preference?

Tags: android, background-color, android-preferences

On Android 4.x I want to change the default color (here is blue) when an item is **pressed** in Preference:
[image]

How can I do that? Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the color of a checked menu item in a navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer)

Comment: show us your them ?   backround color might work in this situation

Answer (score 0):

You should redefine the color accent for Preferences in your styles.xml for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        // your relevant items 
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>
    </style>


   <style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">  
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> // here for the ripple color
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item> 

    </style>
</resources>
```

`parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material"` it is to get a material style like , you can use this parent by addind in your build.gradle :
`compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.3.1'`

Sorry for my english.

Hope this help .