# How to change Item title background in the navigation drawer in Android?

Tags: android, styles, navigation-drawer

I have have a group of items in a navigation drawer menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Group Title">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Import" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Gallery" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I managed to style the menu items following the instruction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer) from stack overflow. Basically modifying these three properties:

This works fine except it only styles the items inside the  tag:

[image]

So my question is: how can I style (color and background) the titles ("Show Apps" and "Others")?

Answer (score 0):

add following codes in styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">#00F</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
    </style>
```

change first line "name" and "parent" with your app defaults