# Selected items in menu

Tags: android, menu, kotlin, navigation-drawer, menuitem

How to correctly display the selected items in the menu? via (with grey background):

[image]

At the moment:

[image]

Why without grey background?

**My XML Menu:**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/night"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_brightness_3_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_1" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nearbyParkingPlaces"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_parking_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_2" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/traffic"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_traffic_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_3" />

    </group>

    ...

</menu>
```

**My code for NavigationItemSelectedListener:**

```
navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.night -> if (menuItem.isChecked) {
                menuItem.isChecked = false
                ...
            } else {
                menuItem.isChecked = true
                ...
            }
            R.id.nearbyParkingPlaces -> if (menuItem.isChecked) {
                menuItem.isChecked = false
                ...
            } else {
                menuItem.isChecked = true
                ...
            }
            R.id.traffic -> if (menuItem.isChecked) {
                menuItem.isChecked = false
                ...
            } else {
                menuItem.isChecked = true
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        false
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or I missed something?

---

If add `android:checkableBehavior="all"` in `<group>` - selected item have grey background, but selected elements are not combine. The previous selected item is reset... I don't understand, why and how fix it?

---

**The solution was found**

Comment: check this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0):

Use selector for your menu background

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/activated_background.xml"
```

and your selector drawable will be like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/normal"/>

            <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />

</selector>
```