# How can i assign code to drawer button?

Tags: android, button, navigation-drawer

I want when a button from the navigation menu is clicked to start a new activity. With the current code nothing happens when the button is clicked. I'm new to Android so plese don't get mad if I don't understand your code and ask some questions.

[image: The button i want the code for is in the blue ccircle]

Here is my **navigation_menu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/nav_account"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home_black_24dp">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/nav_delete"
    android:title="Delete Boards"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_close_black_24dp">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp">
</item>
```

And here is my **mainActivity.java** code for the drawer:

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

 mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.nav_delete) {
            //call new activity
        }
}

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

MainActivity.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.studios.cookie.chanomatic.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:text="Boards"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id = "@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
android:layout_gravity="start">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you can find your answer from here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer/31074133#31074133

Comment: @SonuSanjeev thats what im tring to figure out...

Comment: Screenshot : https://ibb.co/hxuQew

Comment: @MassiGamingRo try my answer

Comment: @MassiGamingRo check my answer you should close drawer when clicking on item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this :**

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_account)
        {
              //your intent
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
   }
```

In main activity implement listner for navigation menu.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

and in activity find navigation view reference and set the listner.

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Full code :

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
mToggle.syncState();
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_icon"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_text_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_text"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: When i put the code it says **Method does not override method from it's super class**.

Comment: @MassiGamingRo you need to implement listner for navigation menu. `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Where should i put navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: @MassiGamingRo after `mToggle.syncState();` this line

Comment: Your code is very apreciated and i'm sure it works but I don't have any nav_view...

Comment: @MassiGamingRo post your drawer activity xml file in question please

Comment: @VishvaDave nice copy paste method onNavigationItemSelected from my answer :)

Comment: @MassiGamingRo every navigation drawer file contains DrawerLayout and inside that navigation view.

Comment: I added to the id of the navigation drawer : "nav_view" but it still dosen't work. Thanks for your patience...

Comment: @MassiGamingRo check my proper answer :)

Comment: @VishvaDave please don't copy paste xml as well as onNavigationItemSelected method.

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya it's not copy paste it is a android studio's template for drawer activity. which will be same for all.

Comment: @MassiGamingRo Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your `onCreate` method:

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Implement lister in your mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

And XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And after that in your onNavigationItemSelected method look like this:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_delete) {
        //call new activity
         }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
     }
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

Did you inflate the navigation menu?
If not, make sure your navigation menu is in the `res/menu` folder and then add:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```