# How to change MenuItem background in android

Tags: android, menuitem, android-appcompat, optionmenu

I want to change a `single menuItem background` in android but it's not working. What I did, set a `appcompat supported actionview` in `MenuItem` and trying to set `background` of `actionview`.

## xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_my_balance"
    android:title="@string/my_balance"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
        />
</menu>
```

## source code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        ImageButton balanceMenu = (ImageButton) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_my_balance));
        balanceMenu.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        balanceMenu.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

But it's not working at all. Also is it possible to getView on MenuItem without set custom `actionview`?

Comment: I tried without invalidate first but it didn't work, so I tested with invalidate but that didn't work either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719173/change-background-color-of-android-menu follow this link

Comment: I already tried that, it crash in 5.0.0. Says cannot set factory because it's already set (somewhere). BTW I am trying to figure out why my code(approach) is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure why your approach is not working but I think it's somehow a contradiction to use *app:showAsAction="never"* together with *app:actionViewClass="whatever"* Are you trying to set an action bar ImageButton or to change an item in the overflow menu?

Comment: I don't want to show this menu in actionbar directly. Instead I want to show it in a list. That's why I used showAsAction="never"

Comment: Then I think you have to use a custom popup window instead of a menu

Answer (score 0):

try this Style from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="ChooseYourParentStyle">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyStyle.PopupMenu_Style</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyle.PopupMenu_Style" parent="ChooseYourParentStyle.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/CreateCustomDrawable</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Already did, not working. I think maybe option menu does not directly use popupMenuStyle.