# Is it possible to make the Android options menu background non-translucent?

Tags: android

The options menu has a translucent background and I would like to make it solid and non-transparent.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
     <item name="android:panelFullBackground">{your color or drawable}</item>
</style>
```

Also, see:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4441
- [How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu)
- Completely overriding menu panel: [Android MenuItem Toggle Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568533/android-menuitem-toggle-button)

Comment: I used `panelBackground` instead of `panelFullBackground` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

set `android:theme="myTheme"`, and define your own theme with whatever colours you want. Read up about [Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html), and look at the android [themes.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=6b3d7407d1c895a3c297e60d5beac98e2d34c271;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 2):

Try this for android 4.0:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">       
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">{your color or drawable}</item>
    </style>
```

Also, the following site generate Action Bar Style :

http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks. Btw, is there any easy way to change text color on the options menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to style a whole theme and just change the options menu background then set the panelFullBackground property to a DRAWABLE RESOURCE of your liking. Setting it to a color directly doesn't work so either make one coloured - 9patch, if you want to save in size -image and set it to that or make a couple and make a selector drawable with an image for each state.

I put my definition in a style that i use for all the activities in my project using:

@drawable/optionsmenu_back

optionsmenu_back being a 9patch image with a solid colour...