# Android want to create a transparent menu

Tags: android, menu, background, transparent

I have seen some posts regarding transparent menu.

I am able to change the background color of menu using the code given in the following link -   [Customizing the Options Menu Background](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/195-customizing-the-options-menu-background)

When I tried to change the background as transparent in the same code like given below, its not working

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.full_trans_bg);
```

instead of a normal image I have tried the transparent image, but its not working.

I just want to change the background color alone not the rest. Bcas I know to get this transparent background by inflating a new layout in the onCreateOptionsMenu() but in this case I want to do everything manually, which is not a motive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a style in `styles.xml`

```
  <style name="myApplicationCustomTheme" parent="@android:Theme">
       <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```

Apply this to your manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/myApplicationCustomTheme"
    android:debuggable="true"
>
```

Also refer to this post.  [Is it possible to make the Android options menu background non-translucent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217886/is-is-possible-to-make-the-android-options-menu-background-non-translucent)

Comment: for menu background use "android:panelBackground"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full code, but try something like this:

```
  view.setBackgroundResource(new Drawable(new Bitmap(R.drawable.full_trans_bg).getBitmapdata());
```

That might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML background color value `#00ff0000` which is transparent in itself.